# How to insert a date in the database in JavaEE?

Tags: java, datetime, jsp, java-ee-8

I have a variable named `targetdate` and I would like to insert a value in my form.

In my Controller, I have this:

```
public static int addStudent(Student studentBean){  
   int status=0;  
   try{  
       Connection con=getConnection();  
       PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into students (targetdate) values(?)");  
       ps.setDate(1,studentBean.getTargetdate());    
       status=ps.executeUpdate();  
   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
   return status;  
}
```

My problem is the line below:

```
ps.setDate(1,studentBean.getTargetdate());
```

I have an error message:

> the method `setDate(int, java.sql.Date)` in the type `preparedstatement` is not applicable for the argument `(int, java.util.Date)`

I am beginner in Java, I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ps.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(studentBean.getTargetdate().getTime()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much ^^